# "No compatible targets were found" eclipse adt plugin error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-version

I don't understand...
In my office I installed Eclipse + Android SDK (API 16) + ADT plugin to develop my own app. When I installed it on my Galaxy Tab and Galaxy Nexus nothing happened and it worked fine. But when I installed all of this on my laptop in my house and imported the eclipse project to installed it again on my devices ADT says that message: "No compatible targets were found". Despite it's the same project, i didn't change a thing and the software is the same...

What can be causing this issue? Any ideas?

I have a meeting this wednesday to start selling the app and it would be great if someone could answer me before that day!! xD

Thanks!!

Comment: Have tried to add SDK path to the eclipse preferences?

Answer (score 0):

Are the ADB drivers for the phone working/installed on the laptop?

if your using windows check the device manager.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have the proper version of the SDK installed on your Eclipse.  You need to make sure you have used the 'SDK Manager' to install the proper Android version, that your build is compiling to what you expect (this is set in the AndroidManifest.xml), and that your emulator or device is targeting the version of the OS you are expecting.

My quess is you don't have the proper Android SDK downloaded.

Comment: I don't think so... because I downloaded SDK number 16 and 17 in my office and in my laptop... and in AndroidManifest I put minSDKVersion = 9 and targetSDKVersion = 15... it worked in my office but not at home... I think, as pvyParts said, it's about the drivers of the devices...